# PHP - delete values within brackets if condition true

Tags: php, preg-match

I'd like to delete the values within brackets only if it contains `"eur" AND "%"` but have a hard time getting started as exploding the string by `"("` didn't get me far.

**Example:**

```
"T-Shirt(grey)(20EUR excl.10% discount)with print" -> "T-Shirt(grey)with print"  

"Jacket(blue)" -> "Jacket(blue)"
```

My initial attempt:

```
$string="T-Shirt(grey)(20EUR excl.10% discount)with print";

$string = explode("(",$string);
foreach($string as $first){
    if(strlen(stristr($first,'eur'))!=0 AND strlen(stristr($first,'%'))!=0){

    }
}
```

Comment: Please showcase some prior attempt.

Comment: Your if statement returns true, so the issue is not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no preg_match in your code :), but here is an example to get you started:

```
$e = '#\([0-9]+(EUR).+(\%)(|.+?)\)#';

$lines = [
"T-Shirt(grey)(20EUR excl.10% discount)with print",
"T-Shirt(grey)(20USD excl.10% discount)with print",
"T-Shirt(grey) with no print",
"Some weird dress(black)(100EUR with 0% discount)",
];
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
        if(preg_match($e,$line,$m))
        {
                print $line. " => " . str_replace($m[0],'',$line)."\n";
        }
}
```

Will produce:

```
T-Shirt(grey)(20EUR excl.10% discount)with print => T-Shirt(grey)with print
Some weird dress(black)(100EUR with 0% discount) => Some weird dress(black)
```

Comment: works well! thanks! only it's case sensitive for the "eur"-match which it shouldn't

Comment: yep, you'll have to define (EUR|eur) or anything like that - that's what regexp is for, after all :)